# Setting a parents value in a childs object's model form in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I wish for one of a parent's variables to be pre-populated in a child's model form specifically a serial number. I have managed to get the serial number as part of the URL but would like to figure out how it can be implemented as a variable on the form page.

**Models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
  serial_number = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=15)

class ProductInstance(models.Model):
  serial_number = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class ProductInstanceCreate(CreateView):
  model = ProductInstance
  template_name = 'myapp/edit_productinstance.html'
  form_class = GunInstanceForm

def get_success_url(self):
   return reverse_lazy ('product-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.serial_number.pk})
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ProductInstanceForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = ProductInstance
    fields = '__all__'
```

**templates/myapp/product_detail.html**

```
...
<a href="{% url 'productinstance_create' serial_number=product.serial_number %}">New</a>
...
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += [  
url(r'^productinstance/(?P<serial_number>[-\w]+)/create/$', views.ProductInstanceCreate.as_view(), name='productinstance_create'),]
```

**templates/myapp/edit_productinstance_form.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}


<h2>Serial Number: {{ serial_number }}</h2>
</br>
<form action="" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</br>
<a href="">Back</a>

{% endblock %}
```

So currently I can create a URL such as: productinstance/D1430913/create/

I now need to know:

1. How to use it as a variable for the title?
2. How to set the the forms default value to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the title:

```
<h2>Serial Number: {{ form.serial_number.value }}</h2>
```

I believe if you modify your CreateView like so and implement the `serial_number_func()` with whatever you need to get the serial number, this will do what you want:

```
class ProductInstanceCreate(CreateView):
  model = ProductInstance
  template_name = 'myapp/edit_productinstance.html'
  form_class = GunInstanceForm

  def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ProductInstanceCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['serial_number'] = serial_number_func()
        return kwargs
```